# How to enroll developer.apple program for multiple years

Tags: iphone, apple-id, developer-program

Yesterday, I enrolled in the `developer.apple` program for one year, for 99 USD. But I want to increase this for more 3 years. Yesterday, I didn't find any option where I can increase the time period. It had only one option: `1 year 99.0 USD` What is the process if I want to enroll in the program for next 3 years?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't enroll for multiple years at one time.  You can only enroll 1 year at a time.  You can read more about renewing your membership [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/renewal/).

You can sign-up for automatic renewal, if you're worried about forgetting to renew.  Just go to your Membership page and check the box for **Auto-Renew Membership**.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I don't wanna do that "Auto Renew" actually. It's ok. :(

Comment: @Tulon - when you sign up for the auto-renewal membership, you will get email notices one month before, and then two weeks before the auto-renewal kicks in.

Comment: OK. I don't have any other option in hand rather than to go for "Auto Renew". Thanks.